# Tag formatting guidelines

Tags: discussion, tags

Can I suggest we discuss some tag guidelines?  IE, what kind of approach should we take to how our tags are created, named, and used.

Answer (score 9):

- Tags of two words should be separated by a dash. So [circularsaw](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circularsaw) should be [circular-saw](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circular-saw), not the other way around.  Synonyms may be created when this is seen to avoid both existing.
- We should have tags for tool classes that are used in conjunction with the specific tool, when there is an appropriate one   IE, if it's a question for a particular relatively specific kind of saw (say a hacksaw), it should also get [saw](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saw) in addition to [hacksaw](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hacksaw), or perhaps [hand-saw](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hand-saw).  This is useful if a question that applies to [hacksaw](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hacksaw) also has features that might apply to other similar saws.
- Tags should be singular, unless the thing being created is importantly plural, or is a category.  [toy](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toy) not [toys](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toys), [chair](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chair) not [chairs](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chairs), etc; but [hand-tools](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hand-tools) not [hand-tool](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hand-tool).
- When using verbs like [stain](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stain) or [finish](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finish) the suffix "ing" should be used, unless it has its own term, such as [joinery](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joinery).
- We should have tags focused around:

  - General topics: [storage](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storage), [safety](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety)
  - Tools: [hand-saw](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hand-saw), [screwdriver](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screwdriver), [lathe](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lathe)
  - Materials: [plywood](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plywood), [hardwood](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardwood), [maple](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maple), [danish-oil](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/danish-oil)
  - Methods and practices: [joinery](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joinery), [finishing](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finishing), [turning](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turning)
  - Final products: [toy](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toy),[table](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table)

  and should make an effort to make sure questions that have logical elements of the above have appropriate tags for each (and not just one category).

Comment: This probably should be community-wiki, do you all think?  It's certainly intended that if this is a good start, for others to add to it.

Comment: For sure. I think I would add some to it if it became CW :)

Comment: @BlueIce Done...

Comment: Thanks! Let the official guidelines commence :)

Comment: In regards to the plural do we make synonyms? Or just leave it be since the would be autocompleted..... self answered that one I think.

Comment: What about verb/actions. finish / finishing and stain / staining. I could see arguments for keeping both or forcing synonyms.

Comment: Going against the grain ( See what I did there! ) in the example of [hand-tools] vs [hand-tool] tools flows better IMO

Comment: Updated the guildlines based on http://meta.woodworking.stackexchange.com/a/64/128

Comment: [tag:hand-tools] would be okay if it's a category (a group of hand tools, comprised of awls, screwdrivers, ...).

Comment: [tag:joinery] or [tag:joining]?  All of the other method/process tags are -ing, is [tag:joinery] the exception or is it wrong?

Comment: @Joe We have to use [tag:joinery], even though it breaks formalism. It is the most well-known term for this practice. Visitors would question our merit if we all referred to it as [tag:joining].