# Retag Requests Here

Tags: support, retag-request

Instead of starting a lot of individual meta threads for each routine retag request, this question can serve as a place for us to organize them in one spot. If you have a request, add it as an 'answer' below. If you have any concerns about a suggestion (or need clarification), post it as a 'comment' on that post.

Please keep in mind the [Tag formatting guidelines](https://woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12/10).

Comment: I will remove the obvious 'answers' once they have been completed. Others I may leave some for the time being for further comment and consideration.

Comment: @RobertCartaino that makes sense

Answer (score 4):

The [making-lumber](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/making-lumber) tag should be renamed [milling](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/milling), then create the synonym "making-lumber" that points back to [milling](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/milling).

Answer (score 1):

On [this question](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/425/making-biscuits-by-hand), someone added [biscuit-joinery](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biscuit-joinery) which should probably just be [joinery](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joinery), which it already had.

Comment: I had originally had that tag on my question but figured it was to unique and removed it. How many types of joinery are out there... like at least 2 I figure.

Comment: There are many types of joinery, I'm just not sure that we need tags for each one. I bring it up here for discussion among the group.

Comment: My comment was to be taken sarcastically :( I agree that we don't need tags of that much detail for joinery. Similarly dont think we need that spawl for some other technique tags as well.

Comment: Well, next time use the sarcasm font! Sheesh!  ;) (doncha just love teh internet?)

Comment: I think in the long-term where we have thousands and thousands of questions, having tags for subsets of joinery could be helpful. I'd vote to keep both.

Comment: @Matt - Valid. It might be a bit early to start consolidating tags.

Comment: That comment had some odd English. What I meant was that we should allow those tags for now. Later on, if they prove useless, we can remove then. It will be easier to do that then to later reconsider and try to find all the biscuit-joinery questions and retag them I think

Comment: I agree with drs; it would be very helpful to be able to search for dovetail or mortise-and-tenon questions without having to dig through all the other questions tagged with `joinery`.

Answer (score 1):

Is [saw](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saw) simply to vague? On its own outright yes but it would give context with other tags. Longterm it might be fine.

Comment: I agree that `saw` is too vague and doesn't add much value over `power-tools` or `hand-tools`

Answer (score 0):

I don't feel that a tag for manufacturers like, [dewault](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dewault), is a good idea but I could be wrong. In some questions it is important to add details like make and model of tools but I could see tags like this getting out of hand.

Comment: I agree on avoiding manufacturer tags, unless, possibly, there is a manufacturer who has become synonymous with a product like "Kleenex"/"tissue".

Comment: Maybe break your tag questions into separate posts, that way each can be voted on and discussed independently.

Comment: @drs moved the portions not part of the discussion into other answers.

Answer (score -2):

[glue](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glue) is really just a subset of [joinery](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joinery).

Answer (score -2):

[lathe](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lathe) is really just a subset of [turning](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turning).

Comment: I can see a use for both. While a lathe is pretty much only used for turning, they are different things and they should both exist.  Questions with [tag:lathe] would ask about the tool while questions with [tag:turning] would ask about the technique, etc.

Answer (score -2):

[chisel](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chisel) is really just a subset of [blade](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blade), which is just a subset of [tools](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools).

Comment: There are *lots* of subsets of [tag:tools] :). I think they're ok.

Answer (score -2):

[screws](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screws) is really just a subset of [joinery](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joinery).

Comment: As with lathe/turning and biscuit-joinery/joinery, I'd vote to keep both. It's ok to have subsets.

Answer (score -3):

[assembly](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assembly), which I created, is a synonym for [joinery](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joinery).

Comment: I can't decide about this...

Comment: Sorry, IMHO assembly and joinery are not the same thing.  Joinery is the art of joining two pieces of wood together, it requires skill, patience and know-how.  Sure, You "assemble" a joint, but I would not call the overall attachment of pieces into a piece "joinery."